# What options do I have for implementing custom code issues and fixes in Visual Studio 2012 and above?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, roslyn

I have experimented with implemented Roslyn Code Issues and Fixes in Visual Studio 2013 when they discussed it in BUILD 2014.

We want to be able to right custom rules that will cause either compiler errors or warning and additionally if possible give visual feedback in Visual Studio.

If possible, it would be nice to provide this in VS2012 and later, but the last time I checked, the ability to do this through Roslyn was in 2013 and later.

I do not have any specific attachment to Roslyn, but I am not aware of the ability to do this elsewhere.

Is there any other way to provide custom code issues and fixes int he IDE, or is it only through Roslyn in 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this using Roslyn on Visual Studio 2015.

The Roslyn End User Preview for 2013 is a much older version of the APIs and is not supported.

Comment: Do we have any idea whether this is something that is worth investing time into implementing?

Comment: To get to the level of integration for Roslyn diagnostics in Visual Studio 2015 there's been a half of a dozen developers working on it for quite some time, with the assistance of many other teams across Visual Studio. It's hard to make a quick experience that performs poorly. It's _really hard_ to make a great experience. Obviously I'm biased as a developer of VS2015, but hopefully there's enough value there to overcome any problems of the move. (And hopefully there aren't problems if we did our job right.)